# Parse XML with QXmlStreamReader

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qvector, qxmlstreamreader

I created this xml file with [`QXmlStreamWriter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamwriter.html):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Draw>
    <Input>
        <Column title="A"/>
        <Column title="B"/>
        <Column title="C"/>
        <Column title="D">
            <item id="0">Bayer Leverkusen</item>
            <item id="1">Benfica</item>
            <item id="2">Villareal</item>
            <item id="3">Montpellier</item>
        </Column>
    </Input>
</Draw>
```

I would like to create a Vector of String containing all the items inside the tag `Column title="D"`: Now, I know how to create a `QVector` and how they fit elements on the inside, I just have to figure out how I can do this by extrapolating information from an xml file.

Can you help me?

Comment: For more complex xml parsing like this you could try using XQuerys  from within Qt http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/xmlprocessing.html. To use them you need to have the xmlpatters enabled in your .pro file (QT += xmlpatterns)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`QXmlStreamReader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html) to iterate through the XML elements and find the `<Column title="D">` element. Once you found it, the [`readNextStartElement()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html#readNextStartElement) in combination of [`skipCurrentElement()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html#skipCurrentElement) can be used to read its all child elements.

Let's assume that the XML document you shown in your examle can be read from the `xmlDocument` object. To extract all `<item>` elements from `<Column title="D">` element with appropriate error checking, you can do the following:

```
QXmlStreamReader xmlIterator(xmlDocument);
QVector<QString> output;

for(; !xmlIterator.atEnd(); xmlIterator.readNext()) {
    if(isStartElementOfColumnD(xmlIterator)) {
        while(xmlIterator.readNextStartElement()) {
            if(isItemElement(xmlIterator))
                output.append(xmlIterator.readElementText());
            else
                xmlIterator.skipCurrentElement();
        }
    }
}

if(xmlIterator.hasError())
    qCritical() << "Error has occurred:" << xmlIterator.errorString();
else
    qDebug() << output;
```

In the example above I used two predicates to hide the long and hardly readable validation of `xmlIterator`. These are the following:

```
inline bool isStartElementOfColumnD(const QXmlStreamReader& xmlIterator) {
    return xmlIterator.isStartElement() && xmlIterator.name() == "Column" &&
            xmlIterator.attributes().value("title") == "D";
}
inline bool isItemElement(const QXmlStreamReader& xmlIterator) {
    return xmlIterator.name() == "item" &&
            xmlIterator.attributes().hasAttribute("id");
}
```

Sample result:

```
QVector("Bayer Leverkusen", "Benfica", "Villareal", "Montpellier")
```

Answer (score -1):

I would write it in the following way:

```
QVector<QString> store;

[..]
if (reader.readNextStartElement() && reader.name() == "Draw") {
    while (reader.readNextStartElement() && reader.name() == "Input") {
        while (reader.readNextStartElement()) {
            QXmlStreamAttributes attr = reader.attributes();
            if (reader.name() == "Column" && attr.value("title").toString() == "D") {
                while(!(reader.isEndElement() && reader.name() == "Column")) {
                    if (reader.isStartElement() && reader.name() == "item") {
                        QString text = reader.readElementText();
                        store.append(text);
                    }
                    reader.readNext();
                    if (reader.hasError()) {
                        // Handle error.
                        QString msg = reader.errorString();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                reader.readNext();
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    reader.raiseError("Expected <Draw> element");
}
[..]
```

Comment: That inner-most while loop looks like it would loop forever in case of parsing error.